# set nginx server_name variable from command

Tags: command-line, nginx, docker

```
root@username:/home/dokku/appname# cat nginx.conf

server {
  listen      [::]:80;
  listen      80;
  server_name appname.wrongname.co.uk ;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/appname-access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/appname-error.log;
```

**Part 1:** How do I update the server_name variable from the command line?

**Bonus round:** Any idea why dokku (for docker) is mis-naming my server all of a sudden? It has recently started calling things `appname.dokku.me` where as before it was correctly calling new apps 'appname.servername.co.uk'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your global `/home/dokku/VHOST` file must have been overwritten with `dokku.me`. Check that, as well as the `/home/dokku/APP/VHOST` file.

Answer (score 1):

you can use sed command

```
cp /home/dokku/appname/nginx.conf /home/dokku/appname/nginx.conf.backup
sed -i 's/appname.wrongname.co.uk/appname.dokku.me/g' /home/dokku/appname/nginx.conf
```

in this command search a content in the specific file and replace it with new content format for use it :

```
sed -i 's/searchForContent/replacementNewContent/g' addressToFile
```

Comment: What does it do? Can you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: sure in this command search a content in the specific file and replace it with new content format for use it : sed -i 's/searchForContent/replacementNewContent/g' addressToFile

Comment: Please, update your answer, instead of writting in the comment section